Adding Custom GoogleFonts in Flutter Project
uses-material-design: true
To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
assets:
- assets/
  - google-fonts/:
     - fonts/:
      - OpenSans-Bold.ttf
      - OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf
      - OpenSans-Regular.ttf
      

[teach_me] dart pub get --no-example
Error on line 85, column 7 of pubspec.yaml: While parsing a block collection, expected '-'.
╷
85 │       - google-fonts/:
│       ^
╵
exit code 65
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: ProcessException: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.
Command: C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dartaotruntime.exe --disable-dart-dev C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\frontend_server_aot.dart.snapshot --sdk-root C:\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --target=flutter --no-print-incremental-dependencies -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --no-link-platform --packages D:\project\project1.dart_tool\package_config.json --output-dill D:\project\project1.dart_tool\flutter_build\56dd6d8f642b761d78feba76ae5c6578\program.dill --depfile D:\project\project1.dart_tool\flutter_build\56dd6d8f642b761d78feba76ae5c6578\kernel_snapshot_program.d --incremental --initialize-from-dill D:\project\project1.dart_tool\flutter_build\56dd6d8f642b761d78feba76ae5c6578\program.dill --source file:///D:/project/project1/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --source package:flutter/src/dart_plugin_registrant.dart -Dflutter.dart_plugin_registrant=file:///D:/project/project1/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --verbosity=error package:project1/main.dart
I am trying to add google fonts in my flutter project but always its showing error

As you can see, you have an extra space before - fonts/:

After downloading your ttf or otf files, add them in the directory you want usually assets directory in the project level and to be more classified you should store otf or ttf files within fonts directory and all within that assets.
To be visually clear, i mean this file hierarchy:
├── ios
├── android
├── assets/
│   ├── fonts/
│   │   ├── OpenSans-Bold.ttf
│   │   ├── OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf
│   │   └── OpenSans-Regular.ttf
│   ├── images
│   └── otherAssets
└── lib

and in your pubspec.yaml you should add these assets like the following:
flutter:

  fonts:
    - family: OpenSans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400

and you are done, here's how to use it:
Text(
'Open sans Text',
fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
)
        

At last, i should inform you that downloading all styles of the same font is a good practice because it increases the font rendering quality, btw: using only one ttf file will do the work and will appear as you constructed it using TextStyle but flutter simulate the font shape, it's not the original one.
